# Template deduction ambiguous

Tags: c++, c++17

I am confused by rvalue concept of c++ now.
I wrote the code below to check my understanding of rvalue is correct. But it turns out it it's not. I was expecting the output would be `"T&&"` but instead `"T"` was printed. Why?

To make it print `"T&&"`, which part of the code requires change?

Thank you.

```
template <typename T>
struct printer {
    printer(T t)
    { 
        cout << "T" << endl;
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct printer<T&&> {
    printer(T&& t)
    {
        cout << "T&&" << endl;
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct printer<T&> {
    printer(T& t)
    {
        cout << "T&" << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    printer a(make_unique<int>(5));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I assume you don't expect `printer<std::unique_ptr<int>&&> a(..)` as answer.

Comment: If you are new to rvalue concept, I recommend you not to learn it along with templates.

Comment: See forwarding references here:  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference  `T&&` has two meanings.  As @xskxzr says mixing rvalue references with the concept of template forwarding references maybe confusing you.

Comment: I don't understand this question. There's no ambiguous deduction here. Is the question about class template argument deduction? What's the source of confusion?

Comment: i believe @RichardCritten is right. if you like talks, scott meyers gave an excellent one called "type deduction and why you care"  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wQxj20X-tIU (it's an hour well invested!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "T" was printed. Why?

Automatic deduction guides only consider primary template, not the specialization, so only

```
template <typename T> printer(T) -> printer<T>;
```

is generated.

> To make it print "T&&", which part of the code requires change?

You may add deduction guide:

```
template <typename T> printer(T&&) -> printer<T&&>;
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d7c811772bc3241d)

Note: that deduction guide would also works for `printer<T&>`.
You won't have `printer<T>` anymore with that guide.